# Displaying date and time in the file name

Tags: c

I'm trying to create a file with the current date and time (seperated by underscores) as the file name, but I get the following error when compiling:

```
main.c:45:31: error: ‘%02d’ directive writing between 2 and 11 bytes into a region of size between 1 and 17 [-Werror=format-overflow=]
   45 |   sprintf(fileName,"%04d_%02d_%02d_%02d_%02d_%02d",ptm->tm_year + 1900, ptm->tm_mon+1, ptm->tm_mday, ptm->tm_hour, ptm->tm_min,ptm->tm_sec);
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
```

How do I suppress this warning/solve this issue?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  time_t rawtime;
  time(&rawtime);
  struct tm * ptm = localtime(&rawtime);
  char fileName[25];
  sprintf(fileName,"%04d_%02d_%02d_%02d_%02d_%02d",ptm->tm_year + 1900, ptm->tm_mon+1,
    ptm->tm_mday, ptm->tm_hour, ptm->tm_min,ptm->tm_sec);
}
```

Comment: The `%02d` format *may* write more than two digits. You should probably use `strftime` for this.

Comment: As @Cheatah suggests, using `strftime` such as `strftime(fileName, 25, "%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S", ptm);` would be the best solution.
Alternatively, if you are sure the warning is false positive, you can
suppress it by modifying the compile option `-Werror=format-overflow=2`
to `-Werror=format-overflow=1`. You may find it in `Makefile` or relevant
files.

Comment: Thank you both! Solved my issue beautifully

Answer (score 1):

To limit the conversion of `"%02d"` to 2 digits, perform a `% 100u` on the `int` and use `"%02u"`.

```
sprintf(fileName,"%04u_%02u_%02u_%02u_%02u_%02u",
  (ptm->tm_year + 1900) % 10000u, (ptm->tm_mon+1)%100u, ptm->tm_mday%100u,
  ptm->tm_hour%100u, ptm->tm_min%100u, ptm->tm_sec%100u);
```

Or be prepared for the worse case outputs

```
// 5 _ and 6 INT_MIN and \0
char fileName[5 + 6*11 + 1];
sprintf(fileName,"%04du_%02d_%02d_%02d_%02d_%02d",
  ptm->tm_year + 1900, ptm->tm_mon+1, ptm->tm_mday
  ptm->tm_hour, ptm->tm_min, ptm->tm_sec);
```

Comment: A perfect way to explain the general rule *"Don't Skimp on Buffer Size"* `:)` Also a good opportunity for the `snprintf()`, `NULL`, `0`  trick.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach you can take is to use `snprintf (NULL, 0, format, vals...)` to determine the number of characters that would have been written (excluding the terminating null byte) had enough space been available. So you can size `fileName` using:

```c
  char fileName[snprintf(NULL, 0, format, vals...) + 1];
```

In your case that could be:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

int main (void) {
  
  time_t rawtime;
  time(&rawtime);
  struct tm *ptm = localtime(&rawtime);
  
  /* use snprintf (NULL, 0, format, vals...) to find max number of chars
   * required (excluding the terminating null-byte).
   */
  char fileName[snprintf(NULL, 0,"%04d_%02d_%02d_%02d_%02d_%02d",
                        ptm->tm_year + 1900, ptm->tm_mon+1, ptm->tm_mday, 
                        ptm->tm_hour, ptm->tm_min,ptm->tm_sec) + 1];
  
  sprintf(fileName,"%04d_%02d_%02d_%02d_%02d_%02d",
          ptm->tm_year + 1900, ptm->tm_mon+1, ptm->tm_mday, 
          ptm->tm_hour, ptm->tm_min,ptm->tm_sec);
}
```

Also note `argc` and `argv` are not used in your program, so the proper invocation of `main()` is `int main (void)` to make it explicit that your program takes no arguments (and avoid any `-Wunused` warnings...).